# pyqiwi возвращает пустой json

Tags: python, python-3.x, qiwi, pyqiwi

Столкнулся с проблемой в проклятом pyqiwi
При получении истории кошелька вместо списка транзакций мне возвращается что то типо этого [,,,,,,,,,,]
Код:

```
import pyqiwi
import cgi

wallet = pyqiwi.Wallet(token='18d816a4ab9e0****************', number='7909*******')

payments = wallet.history(rows=10, operation="IN")

check_db = checkdb(vkid, uid)
# на табы не смотрите, тут было условие.
    print("Content-type: text/html\n")
    print("""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=text/html; charset=UTF-8/>
        """)
    print("""
        <title>Pay Check</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        """)
    print(payments["transactions"])
    print("""
        </body>
        </html>
        """)
```

Что возвращает payments["transactions"]:

```
 [, , , , , , , , , ]
```

Что возвращает просто payments:

```
{'transactions': [, , , , , , , , , ],
 'next_txn_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 24, 17, 55, 38,
  tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 10800))), 
 'next_txn_id': 12367445038}
```

Qiwi кошелек не пустой.
История в кошельке есть.
Помогите воскресить функцию пожалуйста.